# Problem printing the derefrenced value of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dereference

I'm trying to understand the operations of pointers.

For the following bit of code:

```
void main () {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
    
    int *p = &x;
    int *q = &y;
    int *r = &z;

    //print  with labels the values of x, y, z, p, q, r, *p, *q, *r
    printf("x is: %d\n%y is: %d\nz is: %d\n\n",x,y,z);    
    printf("p is: %d\n%q is: %d\nr is: %d\n\n", p, q, r); 
    printf("*p is: %d\n%**q is: %d\n*r is: %d\n\n", *p, *q, *r); 
}
```

The result using gcc compiler is:

The expected result for the lines:

is:

```
x is: 1
y is: 2
z is: 3

p is: 6422288
q is: 6422284
r is: 6422280

*p is: 00000001
*q is: 00000003
*r is: 76036FED
```

according to my understanding that's not what should come out in the last three rows, they should give the same value as the first reason, is there a reason behind this result or is it correct and I'm missing something?

Comment: There are redundant `%` in your each `printf` after first `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three thoughts:

1. `printf("p is: %d\n%q is: %d\nr is: %d\n\n", p, q, r);` isn't valid. You need to use `%p` to print a pointer.
2. All of your printf statements have too many percent characters in them.
3. I agree with your main point. Assuming you removed the extra percent characters, you should see that `*p is 1, *q is 2, *r is 3`.

https://repl.it/repls/OpenAngelicControlflowgraph#main.c